# What is the best practice for when to do input validation?

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java project involving two classes.  One is the Driver of the project and the other holds the actual functionality of the program.  The driver is going to collect input from the user and the values will be used to create an instance of the other class.  The other class has constraints on what the data can be (ie. one value needs to be below a certain number) and I was wondering when I should validate that the input meets those requirements.  In general is input validation something each class being instantiated worries about or is it something the class collecting the data is supposed to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with anything, "it depends".

Let's not think about the whole application, and instead think of the individual components.  For now we'll call them `ApplicationHost` and `BusinessLogic`.

The `BusinessLogic` component should be fully functional, in and of itself, and usable by any application.  So if there are assumptions or requirements that it has about its inputs, it needs to enforce those.  For example, if you're setting an `int` value and that value must be positive, then the setter should enforce that.  Something as simple as this:

```
public void setSomeValue(int someValue) {
    if (someValue <= 0) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("Some Value must be a positive value.");
    }
    this.someValue = someValue;
}
```

The idea being that it is the *responsibility* of `BusinessLogic` to enforce this constraint.  Any consuming code which attempts to use `BusinessLogic` while violating this constraint would get an error.  `BusinessLogic` itself simply advertises what its constraints are and requires that they be followed.  It doesn't care much about user experience, only about system state.  If the state is invalid, fail fast and loudly.

So then should `ApplicationHost` *also* have this same constraint?  The question you're probably asking is, should that *same exact `if` statement* be ***duplicated*** in `ApplicationHost`?

It depends.

Keep in mind that "code duplication" is not a measure of identical keystrokes.  It is a measure of identical intents and responsibilities.  `ApplicationHost` has no responsibility to maintain the business logic.  It *might*, however, have a responsibility to provide a good user experience.  And in doing so it has a couple of options:

1. Send input directly to the business logic, catch and handle any exception, show a friendly error to the user.
2. Validate input on its own before even invoking the business logic, interacting directly with the user to drive that input first and only when it's valid actually perform the business operation.

The first option means less code, the application layer is mostly a pass-through to the business layer.  However, it also means that in cases where there may be multiple input constraint violations then only the *first* encountered one would generate an error.  Remaining violations wouldn't be caught until each one is corrected individually.

The second option means "duplicating" code.  However, it also tends to produce a much better user experience with less "back and forth" between the application layer and the business layer.  (Imagine a form on a website where you had 5 errors, and had to submit and correct the form 5 times because it could only tell you one error at a time.)

Which is better?  It depends on what you're doing in the application and the desired overall experience.  There is no universal rule.

---

**But how can code duplication be a good thing?**  Well, it isn't.  Not inherently.  In many cases, this isn't a problem.  In fact, you may find that in many cases the validation logic in the two separate layers isn't actually the exact same logic.  They are validating for different purposes, and depending on how much of a pass-through layer vs. translation layer the application is over the business logic, they may even be validating different "shapes" of the data.

If, however, they are resulting in essentially identical validation logic.  Then you may be able to extract from that a third "responsibility" which can be moved to its own class.  A `BusinessLogicInputValidator` if you will.  This can live inside the business logic layer, perhaps even inside the `BusinessLogic` object in simple enough cases.  And it would expose the same operations used by both `BusinessLogic` and `ApplicationHost`.

In this case the code which *performs* the validation would be centralized, and the code which *consumes* that validation logic would be duplicated.  Which is ok, since code which consumes logic isn't itself an element of logic and isn't really subject to the same "code duplication" fears.

Comment: Thank you for your very descriptive answer!  It makes a lot of sense to try and keep duplication of ideas/intent from happening with a 3-rd party validation Class.